# Javascript regex to trim spaces within parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the javascript regex to trim spaces within parenthesis *only*?

For example, given

```
balance( 11010000 ) / balance( 11050000 )
```

it should return

```
balance(11010000) / balance(11050000)
```

Comment: I just started learning regex and don't know where to start

Comment: Well, what is that you want to match/find? You want to match a `(` that is followed by one or more spaces. A corresponding regular expression would be `\( +`. The `(` may have to be escaped (thus the ``\``) because it is also a meta-character in regular expressions. I hope this helps as a start.

Comment: But it won't deals with the spaces which was at the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parenthesis are properly enclosed then you could use the below positive lookahead based regex.

```js
var str = "balance( 11010000 ) / balance( 11050000 )"
alert(str.replace(/ (?=[^()]*\))/g, ""))
alert('balance (1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0)'.replace(/\s(?=[^()]*\))/g, ""))
```